# BouncyCastle - how get expiration date of TimeStampToken

Tags: java, timestamp, bouncycastle

I've got TimeStampToken from TimeStampResponse - response.getTimeStampToken().

I need expiration date of that TimeStampToken, is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible.

From TimeStampResponse extract TimeStampToken:

```
TimeStampToken tok = response.getTimeStampToken();
Store certs = tok.getCertificates(); 
ArrayList<X509CertificateHolder> listCert = new ArrayList(certs.getMatches(null));
X509Certificate cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(listCert.get(0));
expiration = cert.getNotAfter();
```

Warning: in default TimeStampToken does NOT contain certificate, so tok.getCertificates() return NULL. You must set:

```
TimeStampRequestGenerator reqgen = new TimeStampRequestGenerator();
reqgen.setCertReq(true);
```

So your request must contain boolean value, that you want certificate in response.

Hope this help.

Comment: Using your above methods, and ensuring `setCertReq(true)` is called, I'm getting an index out of bounds for the `get(0)` call because the cert list if empty. Is this still valid code for BC 1.6? Is there another way to get the certs?

Comment: I run this code only against BC 152. Are you sure that other side is implemented correctly and doesn't ignore setCertReq(true);?

Comment: This is BC 1.60. I can get the certificate I think, but I can't verify it because I have difficult time parsing the ASN1 structure, so I've been relying on BC's get methods for all the attributes. How can I tell for sure that setCertReq(true) is not being ignored?